# Python dictionary inside __init__() does not appear covered after running coverage.py in PyCharm

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, code-coverage, python-unittest

How do I get all lines of the multi-line dictionary definition show below to indicate full coverage in PyCharm 5.0.3?

All of the lines in `self.font_families_dict` do not appear covered when I run `coverage.py` in PyCharm.

Link to code: [fontparser.py](https://github.com/nueverest/blowdrycss/blob/master/python/fontparser.py)

Link to test: [test_fontParser.py](https://github.com/nueverest/blowdrycss/blob/master/python/unit_tests/test_fontParser.py)

This could be a PyCharm 5.0.3 issue, user error on my part, or something in `coverage.py`.  I've never seen this kind of issue before, and I have multiple classes that initialize dictionaries.

**Note:**

- Green vertical bar on the left indicates that the line is covered.
- Red vertical bar on the left indicates that the line is not covered.

[image]

To be sure the lines were tickled I wrote this test:

```
class TestFontParser(TestCase):
    def test_font_families_dict(self):
        font_parser = FontParser()
        expected = {
            'serif': {
                'georgia', 'palatino', 'times', 'cambria', 'didot', 'garamond', 'perpetua', 'rockwell', 'baskerville',
            },
            'sans-serif': {
                'arial', 'helvetica', 'gadget', 'cursive', 'impact', 'charcoal', 'tahoma', 'geneva', 'verdana',
                'calibri', 'candara', 'futura', 'optima',
            },
            'monospace': {'courier', 'monaco', 'consolas', },
            'fantasy': {'copperplate', 'papyrus', },
        }
        self.assertEqual(font_parser.font_families_dict, expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Restart PyCharm.
- Run Coverage again.

[image]

- Result

[image]